# Input text to foreign key in a form symfony

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, foreign-keys

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('path', FileType::class);
        //$builder->add('expirationData', DateType::class);
        $builder->add('tagTagName', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => Tag::class, 'label' => 'Tag',
        ));
    }
```

How can I associate a "Input text" to the field `tagTagName`

Comment: can you be more precise ?

Comment: Sorry. Form generated by this code is made up by: "title" label and text field; "path" label and input file in the end by a "Tag" label; that is I can't type "Tag" field because there isn't any text field. I would like to know how I can associated to "Tag" label an input text